# Magento 2 : AddAttributeToFilter with AND Condition

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

In product collection, I want to do like :

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $catalog_id])->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('color', ['eq' => 2650]);
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('size', ['eq' => 10]);
```

This above code working properly. But, my attribute collection will be dynamically. So, I want to do like just single **addAttributeToFilter** and this both filter apply.

How to do that?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

wel you can make array and add it there like that :

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(array('color', ['eq' => 2650]), ('size', ['eq' => 10]));
```

or just create a foreach loop to process your array